# Reshaping rows to columns while shared key

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a two-column table, that I want to spread. I know that it is a very popular and well-explored topic here, however, I tried several approaches and didn't get what I wanted. Any suggestions and complaints are welcomed.

```
a = data.frame(names = c(rep(LETTERS[1:5],2)),
               values = c("car", "cat", "melon", "happy", "winter",
                          "train", "cat", "apple", "sad", "summer") ) 

   names values
1      A    car
2      B    cat
3      C  melon
4      D  happy
5      E winter
6      A  train
7      B    cat
8      C  apple
9      D    sad
10     E summer
```

I would like to from `categories` makes columns and from `values` rows.

But there is a problem with shared keys (duplicate rows `2` and `7`), which makes unable to use `spread` or `reshape`.

```
      A   B     C     D      E
    car cat melon happy winter
  train cat apple   sad summer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `pivot_wider` and `unnest`.

```
library(tidyverse)

a %>%
  # change from long to wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = names,
              values_from = values,
              #Add this line to suppress the warning of values not being uniquely identified
              values_fn = list(values = list)) %>% 
  # Unnest each list into separate rows
  unnest(cols = everything())

# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  A     B     C     D     E     
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
#1 car   cat   melon happy winter
#2 train cat   apple sad   summer
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split` and `data.frame` like:

```
data.frame(split(a$values, a$names))
#      A   B     C     D      E
#1   car cat melon happy winter
#2 train cat apple   sad summer
```

In case you don't have the same umber of `values` per `name` you can use:

```
x <- split(a$values, a$names)
data.frame(lapply(x, "length<-", max(lengths(x))))
```

Comment: That works perfectly for the given example, however, while I am trying to apply the solution to my original data (2x1510) I got an error suggesting that arguments differ in number of rows. But the length of the column `names` is equal to the length of column `values`

Comment: The problem is, that you have not the same umber of `values` per `name`. If it's ok to have a list as result use `split(a$values, a$names)`. In case you need a `data.frame` I have updated the answer.

Comment: I applied your solution to my edited example and it almost works. But in the example, Jane didn't report her weight, and after applying your solution `NA` swapped position with a value below

Comment: This looks like an new problem since the update. Maybe the following can come close to what you want: `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(a, cumsum(a$categories == "name")), function(x) x$values[match(unique(a$categories), x$categories)]))`.

Comment: it seems promising, but I may see only numbers inside the result table, however, `NA` is on the right place